# Angulardart - Material Button Component with Toggle Behavior

Tags: angular-dart

It's possible to have the toggle behavior using AngularDart Material Button Component `<material-button>`?

Similar to [material button-toggle](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/examples).

Answer (score 1):

No sorry we don't have that widget as of today. Care to file an issue and highlight it as a feature request?

Comment: Filed the issue as a feature. Thanks! https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/issues/307